# Add condition to last() function in pyspark sql when used by window/partition with forward filling

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The code I am getting is from this link:
https://johnpaton.net/posts/forward-fill-spark/ 
It has some background of the tasks I want to accomplish.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import last

# define the window
window = Window.partitionBy('location')\
               .orderBy('time')\
               .rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)

# define the forward-filled column
filled_column = last(spark_df['temperature'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)

# do the fill
spark_df_filled = spark_df.withColumn('temp_filled_spark', filled_column)
```

Basically, `last()` function is used to find the status of last non-null value. If all values are null, then null is returned.

However, I would like to assign a default value if all columns within that group are null. I tried different ways but not able to figure out.

So basically, if the temperatures are all null for a location, I wanted to have a way to set it with a default value.

```
Some examples:
I want to fill them with default values for the case below:

location  temp                temp
1         null                0
1         null      =====>    0
1         null                0

I do not want to fill them with default values for the case below:

location  temp                 temp
1         null                 null
1          50      ======>      50
1          60                   60
```

Comment: can you show some sample data with the expected output?

Comment: @Vamsi Prabhala: just added a link. Thanks!

Comment: If all values are Null, which default value are you wanting to use?

Comment: @ CPak, maybe 0. This is just an example, in fact, I am resuing the code in the link to accomplish a similar task. Eg, if a certain location is having all null temperature values, I wanted  all the temperatures for that location to be set to 0 instead of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can define another column, to serve as an indicator if any record at a given location contains non-null value. For example:

```
window_2 = Window.partitionBy('location').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)
max_column = max(spark_df['temperature']).over(window_2)
```

Then, use that column together with yours `filled_column` to conditionally fill in the final result:

```
temp_filled_spark = when(max_column.isNull(),0).otherwise(filled_column)
spark_df_filled = spark_df.withColumn('temp_filled_spark', temp_filled_spark)
```

Probably not very elegant or super-performant, but should work.

Comment: Thanks for providing the suggestions. However, this is not the use case for my situation. I only wanted to fill a group with default values when all temperatures values are null.
If some temperatures have initial states missing but having valid temperatures later, I do not want to fill those initial states.

Comment: I somehow overlooked that requirement initially... now updated my answer.